# Compiling graph-tool from source - no useable boost::coroutine found

Tags: boost, ubuntu-14.04, configure, graph-tool

I am currently in the process of compiling v1.13 dev from source. I have generated the configure file using `autogen.sh`. I am running the configure script now using the command `./configure --enable-openmp CXX='g++-5'` however this returns the error `configure: error: No usable boost::iostreams found`. I don’t recall running into this error when I compiled v1.12 but maybe I just don’t remember anymore. I have check the version of boost installed with Anaconda and it tells me that it is up-to-date so I presume I may just have to point the script to the correct location but have not found a solution that works for me online yet. What might I be doing wrong here?

This appears to be the relevant entry in config.log:

```
configure:18704: result: no
configure:18669: checking for exit in -lboost_iostreams-mt-py2.5
configure:18694: g++-5 -o conftest -Wall -Wextra -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0  -std=gnu++14 -DNDEBUG -ftemplate-depth-250 -Wno-deprecated -Wno-unknown-pragmas -O3 -fvisibility=default -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp  -I/home/pmj27/anaconda2/include/python2.7   conftest.cpp -lboost_iostreams-mt-py2.5  -lexpat -lm  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_iostreams-mt-py2.5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:18694: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "graph-tool"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "graph-tool"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.13dev"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "graph-tool 2.13dev"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://graph-tool.skewed.de/issues"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://graph-tool.skewed.de"
| #define PACKAGE "graph-tool"
| #define VERSION "2.13dev"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define __EXTENSIONS__ 1
| #define _ALL_SOURCE 1
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS 1
| #define _TANDEM_SOURCE 1
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| #define OPENMP_MIN_THRESH 300
| #define USING_OPENMP 1
| #define HAVE_LIBM 1
| #define HAVE_LIBEXPAT 1
| #define HAVE_PYTHON "2.7"
| #define HAVE_BOOST /**/
| #define HAVE_BOOST_PYTHON /**/
| #define HAVE_BOOST_IOSTREAMS /**/
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| /* Override any GCC internal prototype to avoid an error.
|    Use char because int might match the return type of a GCC
|    builtin and then its argument prototype would still apply.  */
| #ifdef __cplusplus
| extern "C"
| #endif
| char exit ();
| int
| main ()
| {
| return exit ();
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:18704: result: no
configure:18715: error: No usable boost::iostreams found
```

EDIT: reinstalling boost using `apt-get install libboost-all-dev` means that I can run configure but now I get the following warning:

```
configure: WARNING: No usable boost::coroutine found! Some functionality will be disabled in the library.
```

Answer (score 0):

A, rather lengthy, discussion and solution of this issue can be found here: http://main-discussion-list-for-the-graph-tool-project.982480.n3.nabble.com/Debian-package-and-boost-at-compile-time-td4026383.html